# Customize the OnError data being logged to Execute Sql Task in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have an OnError handler in my SSIS package. I would like to modify the system variables before passing to a Execute SQL Task inside the handler. On a normal data flow task, I can pass the data source to another task for deriving new columns. It is this functionality that I would like but in the error handler. However, dragging the derived column task requires inputs which I cannot provide.

How do I go about making the OnError system variables map to some new derived columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of "columns" only exist in a DataFlow task.   In the rest of the package, there are variables.

In an Event Handler, you can use a Script Task to set the value of package variables, and use a Precedence Constraint to force this to happen before an Execute SQL task.